# Taking screenshot on mobile device using Selenium Webdriver + Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-grid

If I connect my desktop as a hub and a mobile device (ios or android) as a node, will I be able to take a screenshot of a web page on my mobile from the desktop? Can I do it with Selenium Grid + Appium or is any other feature required.

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with Appium or Selenium Grid + Appium. The below code will capture the screenshot and save it as screenshot.jpg

```
WebDriver driver1 = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
File file  = ((TakesScreenshot)driver1).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File("Screenshot.jpg"));
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you also suggest the grid configuration that I need to do? I need to connect one iPhone and one Android phone

Comment: Thanks for the advice!! I've realised that Safari browser does not support taking screenshots on the entire webpage. It takes screen shots of only the visible part of the webpage in the simulator. I've read that its an open issue in github. Or is there any workaround that you can suggest to achieve this purpose?